# Using <apex:param> to set query string parameter that's already defined

Tags: visualforce, apex-param

I have this page

```
<apex:page standardController="contact" recordSetVar="c">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:dataTable value="{!c}" var="var">
            <apex:column>
                <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
                <apex:commandLink reRender="det">{!var.name}
                    <apex:param name="cid" value="{!var.id}" />
                </apex:commandLink>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:dataTable>
        <apex:outputpanel id="det">
            <apex:detail subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.cid}" relatedList="false" title="false" />
        </apex:outputpanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

It works fine  when i call page like

```
https://c.na15.visual.force.com/apex/testpage5
```

But when i call page like this it doesnt

```
https://c.na15.visual.force.com/apex/testpage5?cid=003i000000m6n5GAAQ
```

which means if i give a cid parameter already on page load,then when i select a contact 
value doesn't get updated in apex:detail

Whats happening here?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that it involves the rerender. What happens if you remove the rerender?

Comment: tried removing re-render..doesnt make any difference

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why it doesn't update the parameter, but could you perhaps use a different ID in the URL when loading the page?

```
<apex:detail subject="{!IF($CurrentPage.parameters.cid != null, $CurrentPage.parameters.cid, $CurrentPage.parameters.contactId)}" relatedList="false" title="false" />
```

So you'd use `contactId` when calling the page from elsewhere and just `cid` in the page as before. Seems weird that the parameter can be recycled within the page but not when it's used in the original URL.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to get this to work was when I changed your `<apex:commandLink />` to an `<apex:outputLink />` tag and specified the page name for the value of the link, which creates the appropriate URL on the hyperlinks with the `cid` parameter - and the page works great.

Using the commandLink markup with or without a rerender attribute made no difference here, the detail always showed the Contact details that were initially loaded.

```
<apex:page standardController="contact" recordSetVar="c">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:dataTable value="{!c}" var="var">
            <apex:column>
                <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.ThisPageName}">{!var.name}
                    <apex:param name="cid" value="{!var.id}" />
                </apex:outputLink>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:dataTable>
        <apex:outputpanel id="det">
            <apex:detail subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.cid}" relatedList="false" title="false" />
        </apex:outputpanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: whats the reason why you think we have to explicity pass the page name to outputlink...it also works as laceysnr suggested if you specify a different parameter name from what it is on orginal page load.any reason you can think of?

Comment: If it works without the pagename in the outputLink, that's fine. I did not test that. As for the two parameter name mechanism working: during the commandlink's operation you'll have two parameters being sent to the page controller with the same key, `cid`, one with the value contained in the URL and one from the commandLink's parameter value, and apparently the one from the URL 'wins' in this situation. Both of these values end up in the page parameters collection and multiple values for the same key results in an overwriting "last one wins" situation.